# color filling subitem in listView does not work

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I want the subitem to be colored green if the cell is 1 or red if it is 0. I don't quite understand how to properly subclass the listview so that it works.
I took the subclassing implementation from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2890/Using-ListView-control-under-Win32-API), copying the code related to converting the subitem background to a different color completely.

Judging by the comments to the code, WM_NOTIFY should be called several times, but I have it called only once, what do I need to fix to make the coloring work?

Here's where I left off:

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <commctrl.h>
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

int wWrkPls = 655;
int hWrkPls = 200;

static HWND Matrix = NULL;

static HINSTANCE hInst;

LRESULT CALLBACK MainProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp);

void CreateMatrix(HWND hWnd) {

    HWND Matrix = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, WC_LISTVIEW, L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LVS_REPORT, 0, 0, wWrkPls - 18, hWrkPls - 38, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    DWORD dwStyle = SendMessage(Matrix, LVM_GETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE, 0, 0);
    dwStyle |= LVS_EX_GRIDLINES;
    SendMessageW(Matrix, LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE, 0, dwStyle);

    dwStyle = ListView_GetExtendedListViewStyle(Matrix);
    dwStyle |= LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT;
    ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(Matrix, dwStyle);

    ::Matrix = Matrix;

    LVCOLUMN lvColumn;
    lvColumn.mask = LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        lvColumn.cx = 30;
        lvColumn.pszText = (LPWSTR)L" ";
        SendMessage(Matrix, LVM_INSERTCOLUMN, i, (LPARAM)&lvColumn);

    }

    LVITEM lvItem;
    lvItem.mask = LVIF_STATE | LVIF_TEXT;
    lvItem.state = LVIF_PARAM;
    lvItem.stateMask = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
        lvItem.iItem = i;
        lvItem.pszText = (LPWSTR)L"0";
        SendMessage(Matrix, LVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&lvItem);
    
        for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++) {

            lvItem.iSubItem = j;
            lvItem.pszText = (LPWSTR)L"0";
            SendMessage(Matrix, LVM_SETITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&lvItem);

        }
    
    }

}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPr, LPSTR args, int ncmdshow) {

    WNDCLASS WindowClass = { 0 };
    //WindowClass.hbrBackground = CreatePatternBrush(LoadBitmap(hInst, 0));
    WindowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    WindowClass.hInstance = hInst;
    //WindowClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInst, 0);
    WindowClass.lpszClassName = L"MainWindClass";
    WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = MainProc;

    ::hInst = hInst;

    if (!RegisterClassW(&WindowClass)) {

        return -1;

    }

    int wCntr = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) / 2;
    int hCntr = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) / 2;

    HWND MainWindow = CreateWindowA("MainWindClass", "", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, wCntr - (wWrkPls / 2), hCntr - (hWrkPls / 2), wWrkPls, hWrkPls, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    MSG MainMsg = { 0 };
    while (GetMessage(&MainMsg, NULL, NULL, NULL)) {

        TranslateMessage(&MainMsg);
        DispatchMessage(&MainMsg);

    }

    return 0;

}

LRESULT ProcessCustomDraw(LPARAM lp)
{
    LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW lplvcd = (LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW)lp;

    switch (lplvcd->nmcd.dwDrawStage) {
    
        case CDDS_PREPAINT: //Before the paint cycle begins

            return CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;

        case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT: { //Before an item is drawn
    
            return CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW;
        }
        break;

        case CDDS_SUBITEM | CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT: { //Before a subitem is drawn
    
            switch (lplvcd->iSubItem) {
        
                case 0: {
        
                    lplvcd->clrText = RGB(255, 255, 255);
                    lplvcd->clrTextBk = RGB(240, 55, 23);
                    return CDRF_NEWFONT;

                }
                break;

                case 1: {
        
                    lplvcd->clrText = RGB(255, 255, 0);
                    lplvcd->clrTextBk = RGB(0, 0, 0);
                    return CDRF_NEWFONT;

                }
                break;

                case 2: {
        
                    lplvcd->clrText = RGB(20, 26, 158);
                    lplvcd->clrTextBk = RGB(200, 200, 10);
                    return CDRF_NEWFONT;

                }
                break;

                case 3: {
        
                    lplvcd->clrText = RGB(12, 15, 46);
                    lplvcd->clrTextBk = RGB(200, 200, 200);
                    return CDRF_NEWFONT;

                }
                break;

                case 4: {
        
                    lplvcd->clrText = RGB(120, 0, 128);
                    lplvcd->clrTextBk = RGB(20, 200, 200);
                    return CDRF_NEWFONT;

                }
                break;

                case 5: {
        
                    lplvcd->clrText = RGB(255, 255, 255);
                    lplvcd->clrTextBk = RGB(0, 0, 150);
                    return CDRF_NEWFONT;

                }
                break;
        
            }

        }

    }
    
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MainProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {

    switch (msg) {

    case WM_NOTIFY: {
    
        LPNMLISTVIEW pnm = (LPNMLISTVIEW)lp;

        if (pnm->hdr.hwndFrom == Matrix && pnm->hdr.code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW) {
            SetWindowLong(hWnd, 0, (LONG)ProcessCustomDraw(lp));

        }

    }

    break;

    case WM_CREATE: {

        CreateMatrix(hWnd);

    }

    break;

    case WM_DESTROY: {

        PostQuitMessage(0);

    }

    break;

    default:

        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);

    }

}
```

Comment: `SetWindowLong(hWnd, 0, (LONG)ProcessCustomDraw(lp));` is not how you return a result from a window procedure. You want `return ProcessCustomDraw(lp);` Also, not all code paths in MainProc return a value.

Comment: Why do you have a [`#pragma once`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/once?view=msvc-170) in the **source** file?  Are you planning on `#include` the source file in other files?  The `#pragma once` is used *inside* a header file to prevent that header file from being included multiple times.  Search the internet for "C++ include guard".

Comment: FYI, you are programming in C++, so you can remove the `C` tag.  The phrase `::Matrix` is not valid in C, because C doesn't have namespaces.

Comment: Side note: `#pragma once` is an odd thing to see in a file full of data and function definitions. It's a guard against including a header file more than once in a single [translation unit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1106149/4581301). Definitions in a header are generally a bad idea because even if it's only included once in a translation unit, it's easy to include in multiple translation units leading to multiple definition errors when the translation units are linked together into an executable.

Comment: If this is a source file, it should never be included and thus has no need for include guards. If it's a header file, you don't want it to contain definitions.

Comment: FYI, your function, `ProcessCustomDraw()`, does not `return` for some cases.  For example, if the `switch` value doesn't have any matching cases for every possible value.

Comment: Your `MainProc()` lies.  The declaration (signature) says it *always* returns a value.  After processing a message, it doesn't return a value, except in the `default` case.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews, I understand my mistake. This is not the main code of the application - just a glue of the main components. I accidentally added from the header file.
As I understand you, my function does not return the changed window to me. What do I need to change in this case so that the `MainProc()` function returns the resulting listview?

Comment: @ Raymond Chen
Yay! I managed to paint the cells! Thank you for your help and everyone who participated in my problem!

Comment: Now we need to figure out how to bind the color change to the value inside each `iSunItem`. Is it possible to do this inside `ProcessCustomDraw()`? Maybe you could pass the text of `iSunItem` as a parameter to the function, but how...?
P.S. My code changes the colors in the columns depending on the number of `iSunItem`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help! I fulfilled my request as follows. The topic is closed.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <commctrl.h>


int wWrkPls = 655;
int hWrkPls = 200;

static HWND Matrix = NULL;

static HINSTANCE hInst;

LRESULT CALLBACK MainProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp);

void CreateMatrix(HWND hWnd) {

    HWND Matrix = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, WC_LISTVIEW, L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LVS_REPORT, 0, 0, wWrkPls - 18, hWrkPls - 38, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    DWORD dwStyle = SendMessage(Matrix, LVM_GETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE, 0, 0);
    dwStyle |= LVS_EX_GRIDLINES;
    SendMessageW(Matrix, LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE, 0, dwStyle);

    dwStyle = ListView_GetExtendedListViewStyle(Matrix);
    dwStyle |= LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT;
    ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(Matrix, dwStyle);

    ::Matrix = Matrix;

    LVCOLUMN lvColumn;
    lvColumn.mask = LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        lvColumn.cx = 30;
        lvColumn.pszText = (LPWSTR)L" ";
        SendMessage(Matrix, LVM_INSERTCOLUMN, i, (LPARAM)&lvColumn);

    }

    LVITEM lvItem;
    lvItem.mask = LVIF_STATE | LVIF_TEXT;
    lvItem.state = LVIF_PARAM;
    lvItem.stateMask = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
        lvItem.iItem = i;
        lvItem.pszText = (LPWSTR)L"0";
        SendMessage(Matrix, LVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&lvItem);

        for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++) {

            lvItem.iSubItem = j;
            lvItem.pszText = (LPWSTR)L"1";
            SendMessage(Matrix, LVM_SETITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&lvItem);

        }

    }

}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPr, LPSTR args, int ncmdshow) {

    WNDCLASS WindowClass = { 0 };
    //WindowClass.hbrBackground = CreatePatternBrush(LoadBitmap(hInst, 0));
    WindowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    WindowClass.hInstance = hInst;
    //WindowClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInst, 0);
    WindowClass.lpszClassName = L"MainWindClass";
    WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = MainProc;

    ::hInst = hInst;

    if (!RegisterClassW(&WindowClass)) {

        return -1;

    }

    int wCntr = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) / 2;
    int hCntr = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) / 2;

    HWND MainWindow = CreateWindowA("MainWindClass", "", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, wCntr - (wWrkPls / 2), hCntr - (hWrkPls / 2), wWrkPls, hWrkPls, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    MSG MainMsg = { 0 };
    while (GetMessage(&MainMsg, NULL, NULL, NULL)) {

        TranslateMessage(&MainMsg);
        DispatchMessage(&MainMsg);

    }

    return 0;

}

LRESULT ProcessCustomDraw(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lp) {

    LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW lplvcd = (LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW)lp;

    TCHAR szText[10];

    ListView_GetItemText(hWnd, lplvcd->nmcd.dwItemSpec, lplvcd->iSubItem, szText, 100);

    switch (lplvcd->nmcd.dwDrawStage) {

        case CDDS_PREPAINT: { //Before the paint cycle begins

            return CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;

        }
        break;

        case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT: { //Before an item is drawn

            return CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW;

        }
        break;

        case CDDS_SUBITEM | CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT: { //Before a subitem is drawn

            if (wcscmp(szText, L"1") == 0) {
        
                lplvcd->clrTextBk = RGB(0, 255, 0);
        
            }

            else {
        
                lplvcd->clrTextBk = RGB(255, 0, 0);
        
            }

            return CDRF_NEWFONT;
        }

    }

}

LRESULT CALLBACK MainProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {

    switch (msg) {

    case WM_NOTIFY: {

        LPNMLISTVIEW pnm = (LPNMLISTVIEW)lp;

        if (pnm->hdr.hwndFrom == Matrix && pnm->hdr.code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW) {

            return ProcessCustomDraw(pnm->hdr.hwndFrom, lp);

        }

    }
    break;

    case WM_CREATE: {

        CreateMatrix(hWnd);

    }
    break;

    case WM_DESTROY: {

        PostQuitMessage(0);

    }
    break;

    default:

        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);

    }

}
```

Comment: MainProc: Not all control paths return a value.